# The website is not responsive on default mobile browser

Tags: html, css

I have a website which is responsive, but when I access it with some default browsers from Android, it looks like in the photo:

[image]

instead of looking like this:

[image]

I think the problem comes from the css of the big box in which the details for a match are shown ( .game-content). You can inspect the website in order to see more details.
Can anyone give me a suggestion of how I could fix that in order to make sure the website looks the same on all browsers?

Css Code for the box and for the border ( I think they are the root problem):

````css
.game-content {
    position: relative;
    background: #495057;
    height: 355px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```
```
.game-border-right {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-top: 16px;
    height: 79px;
}

.game-odd1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}


.game-odd2 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}

.game-tips {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
````

```html
<div>
    <h3 class="match-heading">{!! $competition_heading !!}</h3>
    <div class="game-content user_info_box">
        <div class="game-top-content">
        <div class="user_info_modal_btn game-time float-left">
            <h6>{{ $match->hour }} GMT</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="game-icon float-right">
           
            <a href="#"class="toggle_in_my_picks" data-url="{{ route('my-picks-toggle', $match->id) }}">
                <i class="{{ $icon_class }} fa-heart wishlist-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-div"></div>
        <div class="user_info_modal_btn game-player-one-content">
            <div class="win-loss-div">
            </div>
            <h6>{{ $match->player_1->flashscore_name }}</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="user_info_modal_btn game-ratio">
            <h6>{{ $match->sets_player1 }}:{{ $match->sets_player2 }}</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="user_info_modal_btn game-player-two-content">
            <h6>{{ $match->player_2->flashscore_name }}</h6>
            <div class="win-loss-div">
               
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-div-odd"></div>
        <div class="user_info_modal_btn game-odds">
            <div class="game-odd1 game-border-right">
                <h6>Odd1</h6>
                <p>{{ $match->odd1 }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="game-odd2 game-border-right">
                <h6>Odd2</h6>
                <p>{{ $match->odd2 }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="game-tips game-border-right">
                <h6>Tips</h6>
                <p>{{ $match->tips }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="game-check-icon">
                {!! $match->prediction_icon !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you will have to narrow it down to a specific problem with a little example piece of code for us sorry not debug a whole real website

Comment: Usually you use some specific css code for certain browers. Which browser is the "default android browser"? What you have you tried and where is your code? And please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I added the css code

Comment: For me it seems that the grey box has no fixed / min-height, maybe the browsers present the page with a different width, which could explain the different height. I am not an expert but I don't get it completely yet.  What is the `.game-border-right`, what is the `.game-content`, please add the corresponding **html code** as well.

Comment: @Christian updated with more css and html

Comment: Still not enough html, the upper box part is missing, see https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=URArRFVKQU

Comment: I added everything

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly setting the minimum height

**(For example -  `min-height: 20px;`)**

for all the elements can be a workaround for the problem described here.

**Note:**

- Responsive design is meant for ***varying screen widths*** only.
- It will not automatically guarantee consistent view across all types
  of browsers.
- Browser type and screen height are out of scope for regular
  responsive design.
- Making the website consistent across different browsers or different screen heights requires aditional development effort